# IOS SDK + Overlay image on video issue

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

I want to overlay image on video file and it is working but image is destroyed on video.

Overlay image:
[image]

While I get video after processing video as below:
[image]

My Code as below:

```
CGSize videoSize = [clipVideoTrack naturalSize];

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"f1.png"];
    CALayer *aLayer = [CALayer layer];
    aLayer.contents = (id)myImage.CGImage;
    aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width,videoSize.height);
    aLayer.opacity = 1;
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width,videoSize.height);
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width,videoSize.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];
```

Please help me to solve this issue so i will able to overlay proper image on video.

Thanks

Comment: Use "f1.png" image  with bigger(double or tripple) size than actual frame size

Answer (score 0):

Use "f1.png" image with bigger(double or tripple) size than actual frame size